# Replace ID with text in rails_admin associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

when using rails_admin for associated objects (like has_and_belongs_to) it shows the ID of the object as the association.
This isn't a great deal for the users so I'ld like to change this for showing the text of the associated object.

Is this solvable?

Here a little example:

First Model:

```
class Menu
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :date, type: Date

  has_and_belongs_to_many :meal
end
```

Second Model:

```
class Meal
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :text, type: String

  has_and_belongs_to_many :menu
end
```

So it shows something like this:

[image: So it shows something like this:]

But I'ld love to see the Text of the meals instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply define a title-method do the trick:

```
def title
  self.text
end
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you check my forum? I have question similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234531/how-can-i-display-the-name-instead-of-an-id-without-the-name-column/44234592?noredirect=1#comment75480115_44234592

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [RailsAdmin DSL](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL) `object_label_method` to change how the field is presented to the user.

In your case, something like this might do the trick:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model Menu do
    list do
      field :meal do
        pretty_value do
          value.text
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but your link leads to the correct solution THX

Comment: @PascalTurbo Care to post the correct answer and mark it as correct (or mark mine as correct, if it worked out)?