# How can I display the name instead of an ID without the name column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have 3 tables, Activity, Activity_type and Itineraries. In activity type, I insert a new entry name => Testing => Example. In my activity, I can use the activity type I created earlier in my dropdown and type a location.

In creating a new itinerary there's a dropdown activity and user(who created the new itinerary and choose what activity for the specific itinerary) but it only shows the activity #1 and user #1. In my list and i think this is the reason why it only display the Activity #1 instead Testing.

Question:

1) In creating a new itinerary how can I change the activity #1 to the specific name?(example: In dropdown it should be Testing not Activity #1)

2)How can I display the name instead of an ID without the name column?

**Activity table**

```
activity_type_id
location_id
```

**Itinerary table**

```
title
created_by
```

**Activity type table**

```
name
description
```

NOTE: I also tried this below but nothing happened

**Rails admin**

```
config.model Itinerary do
list do

  field :title
  # field :schedule
  field :no_of_days
  field :activity
  field :user      
  # field :location      
  # field :activity_type
  # field :location_name
end
create do
  field :title    
end
object_label_method do 
    :activity_label_method
    end
  def activity_label_method
     "#{self.activity_type_id}" 

  end
```

end

**Itinerary model**

```
class Itinerary < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :created_by
  belongs_to :activity
  has_many :activity_itineraries, foreign_key: :created_by

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :no_of_days, presence: true,
               :numericality => true


  def name
    activity_type.name
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a method `title` or `name` in you model as follows,

```
def name
  activity_type.name
end
```

in `rails_admin.rb`, (you may need to modify based on your model associations, it is just the concept from comment from this [`thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526526/6548745))

```
field :activity_type_id, :enum do
  enum do
    Activity.collect {|act| [act.name, act.id]}
  end
end
```

Comment: add `.all` first. `Model.all.collect...` and if you have many columns, this query would be more optimised: `Model.select([:name, :id]).collect..`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145339/discussion-between-angel-and-md-farhan-memon).